How can i display the correct index value on groups on array?
I have the following table called products:
|id| |name|
 81   monitor
 82   keyboard
 83   mouse
 84   headphone

The controller is products_controller.rb with the following code:
 def index
   @products = Product.all
 end

It should display the following result
|Nº|  |name|         |Nº|   |name|
 1     monitor        3      mouse 
 2     keyboard       4      headphone

I tried the following code using SLICE:
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Nº</td>
    <td>Product</td>
  </tr>
  
  <% @products.each_slice(2).each_with_index do |grouped_array,row_index| %> 
  <tr>
     <% grouped_array.each_with_index do |array, column_index| %>
     <td><%= column_index + 1 %></td>
     <td><%= array.name %></td>
     <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

The result using SLICE was:
|Nº|  |name|         |Nº|   |name|
 1     monitor        1      mouse 
 2     keyboard       1      headphone

I tried using in_groups_of
  <% @products.in_groups_of(2).each_with_index do |grouped_array,row_index| %> 
  <tr>
     <% grouped_array.each_with_index do |array, column_index| %>
     <td><%= column_index + 1 %></td>
     <td><%= array.name %></td>
     <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>

The result using in_groups_of was:
|Nº|  |name|         |Nº|   |name|
 1     monitor        1      mouse 
 2     keyboard       1      headphone


For IN_GROUPS_OF code index for element can be calculated like this
Controller change
@half_size = (@products.size / 2.0).round

View change
<% @products.in_groups_of(@half_size).transpose.each_with_index do |grouped_array, row_index| %>
  <tr>
    <% grouped_array.each_with_index do |item, column_index| %>
      <% if item.present? %>
        <td><%= row_index + column_index * @half_size + 1 %></td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>

Works for any amount of elements

Your code is working but its iterating left to right, the result is displaying 1....2
3.....4     and should be displaying     1.......3              .......2 ......4

did you mean that you requirement is table view modification too?

so first column should contain first elements of grouped_array? then your view iterations should be modified

Yes, like the post
